# Получение данных из сигнала в GNU Radio

Tags: python

В рамках проекта к звуковой карте ПК подключен фототранзистор, который фиксирует мерцание светодиода, задаваемые через плату ESP32. Форма сигнала на прикрепленном изображении. Со стороны ESP используется ОnОffКeying. В качестве преамбулы 4 длинных колебания, период каждого из которых равен 3 периодам малого колебания, затем некоторое количество коротких колебаний.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом встроенными методами GNU Radio или с помощью embedded python block посчитать количество коротких колебаний? Например, чтобы при 10 коротких колебаниях после 4 длинных в консоль выводилась цифра 1, при 15 - 2, а без сигнала в консоли был постоянный 0?[image: Форма сигнала с аудиовхода]